# Auth remember system not working as expected

Tags: laravel

I have a confusion about authentication, please make me correct.

I know Laravel has a remember me system with login.

To create session we use `Auth::attempt()`

Here is an example I try to make me understand.

At first I login without remembering session

```
Route::get('/login' , function(){
    $userdata = [
        'email'     => 'rayhan095@gmail.com',
        'password'  => 'my-secret-password'
    ];
    Auth::attempt($userdata);
});
```

Then I check my session status

```
Route::get('check' , function(){
    dd(Auth::check());
});
```

> http://localhost/check

**OUTPUT:**

> true

I close the browser and again check the session status by going `localhost:8000/check`. It again shows me `true`.

Why did it happen?

According to my current knowledge about Authentication, I believe login session will be remembered if and only if I pass second parameter true in `attempt()` method.

I could be remember If I do so

```
Route::get('/login-remember' , function(){
    $userdata = [
        'email'     => 'rayhan095@gmail.com',
        'password'  => '@@1100AAaa##'
    ];
    Auth::attempt($userdata , true);
});
```

**Please make me correct**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember Me sets value of `remember_token` in `users` table.
It is a desired behavior to be automatically logged in again after you re-open the browser. For your issue you can change this in `app/config/session.php` by setting

```
'expire_on_close' => true,
```

So that session will be expired as you close the window.

Comment: It's not about reopening the browser. You can test it. Login without using "remember me", close the browser and reopen it. You will be still logged in.

Comment: This is what I said "It is a desired behavior to be automatically logged in again after you re-open the browser" for **remember me**

Answer (score 1):

When you don't use [Remember Me](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#remembering-users) functionality, the user will be logged in until session will not expire. After that, the user will not be logged in anymore.

You can test it by setting `lifetime` in `config/session.php` to 1 minute.